# SQL: Increase MAXRECURSION without HINT OPTION?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there a global setting at database level or SQL instance level to increase CTE recursion limit?

Comment: I have to hazard to ask why you want to do this. Chaning the default max recursion to 0 (if you were able to) could be a very bad idea if someone creates a poorly written (infinitely recursing) CTE. The default limit is there for a reason, and hence why it has to be explicitly overruled each time.

Comment: @Larnu This is to have temporary fix for the recursion, that the better option is to eliminate CTE recursion with different logic

Comment: If it's temporary, then hard code it till what ever it is you are fixing is fixed. not sure what your latter part of that sentence means i'm afraid.

Comment: Well @Larnu change management takes time, configuration do not. Thanks, for your input.

Answer (score 1):

No, not by default you can't. You could use one of the tips provided here:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/134333/change-the-system-wide-default-for-maxrecursion